# Remove customer form attribute

Tags: php, attributes, magento-1.7

I have added the custom attributes using

```
$setup->addAttribute('customer','default_business',array(
      'type'               => 'int',
        'label'              => 'Default Business Address',
       'input'              => 'text',
       'backend'            => 'orancustomer/customer_attribute_backend_business',
        'required'           => false,
       'sort_order'         => 200,
      'visible'            => 0,
      'global' =>1,
        'user_defined' => 1,));


$attr = $eavConfig->getAttribute('customer', 'default_business');
$attr->setData(  'used_in_forms', array('customer_account_create', 'customer_account_edit', 'checkout_register')///*'adminhtml_customer',*/
)->save();
```

It worked as expected. but when  I tried to remove it,

```
$installer->removeAttribute('customer', 'default_business');
```

It was removed sucessfullu from  eav_attribute table. but in the admin section I am getting the following error
     Fatal error: Call to a member function getBackend() on a non-object in D:\xampp\htdocs\magoran\app\code\core\Mage\Eav\Model\Entity\Collection\Abstract.php on line 515

And when   I tried to debug I found that it is still searching for  default_business attribute . It is still searching the attribute in manage customer page. Here is the query i found during debugging

```
 SELECT `eav_attribute`.* FROM `eav_attribute` WHERE (`eav_attribute`.`attribute_code`='oran_company') AND (entity_type_id = :entity_type_id)
 BIND: array (
 ':entity_type_id' => '1', 
 )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that it was due to the  fieldset in the config.xml .  After I removed it from fieldset of the config.xml of  my custom module, the erro was fixed, Also there was one more thing I  found that it is not compulsory to add the newly added attributes in fieldset.